# Getting started with Angular 2 and Nativescript development on angular-seed-advanced by Nathan Walker?

Tags: lazy-loading, angular2-nativescript, boilerplate, angular-seed

I have started experiments with angular-advanced -seed by Nathan Walker based on angular-seed by Minko Gechev.I created another component called settings and created basic routing in this seed and find out how it works.
I have some doubts:

1. Is it possible to execute and show angular 2 based dependencies on
   native platforms?
2. How is this seed differ from normal apps generated using Native
   script CLI?
3. Is to possible to apply lazy loading common for all platforms?
4. Any other starter angular 2 based boilerplates to kickstart
   development on the web and native platforms?

Comment: 1. What do you mean with "show angular 2 based dependencies"? 2. What's a "normal app"? 3. Are you asking about lazy loading data or framework? 4. Try https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries

Comment: 1. Think about a datatable is added to angular 2 via npm. The datatable may have some material design sub components. How can I make it possible to work with native application?

Comment: 2.  Normal native script app in the sense. Those apps created using tns create command.

Comment: 3.Lazy loading data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Answer to question 1:**

No, your existing web (sub) components in HTML won't work with NativeScript.

You will need to redefine the view (template) from HTML to NativeScript XML and possibly use plugins.

In addition, you will likely need to rewrite some of the code in existing Angular components if you have tight coupling between components and existing HTML views.

**Answer to question 2:**

The NativeScript CLI will generate different code depending on what template you specify on the command line.

**Answer to question 3:**

Yes, you can create a reusable service layer component and, for example, use RXJS https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554338/882912

**Answer to question 4:**

https://github.com/NativeScript/sample-Groceries