# Angular - best way to cache http response

Tags: angular, http, typescript, caching

I have a lot of services with requests to rest service and I want to cache data receive from server for further usage.
Could anyone tell what is the best way to cash response?

Comment: There's a section about caching in the HttpClient documentation. What have you tried so far and what didn't work for you?
https://angular.io/guide/http#caching

Comment: Thank's for response!

Answer (score 7):

You will find multiple answers here: [Angular 2 cache observable http result data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41554156/angular-2-cache-observable-http-result-data/)

I would recommend to build simple class Cacheable<> that helps managing cache of data retrieved from http server or other any other source:

```
declare type GetDataHandler<T> = () => Observable<T>;

export class Cacheable<T> {

    protected data: T;
    protected subjectData: Subject<T>;
    protected observableData: Observable<T>;
    public getHandler: GetDataHandler<T>;

    constructor() {
      this.subjectData = new ReplaySubject(1);
      this.observableData = this.subjectData.asObservable();
    }

    public getData(): Observable<T> {
      if (!this.getHandler) {
        throw new Error("getHandler is not defined");
      }
      if (!this.data) {
        this.getHandler().map((r: T) => {
          this.data = r;
          return r;
        }).subscribe(
          result => this.subjectData.next(result),
          err => this.subjectData.error(err)
        );
      }
      return this.observableData;
    }

    public resetCache(): void {
      this.data = null;
    }

    public refresh(): void {
      this.resetCache();
      this.getData();
    }

}
```

**Usage**

Declare Cacheable<> object (presumably as part of the service):

```
list: Cacheable<string> = new Cacheable<string>();
```

and handler:

```
this.list.getHandler = () => {
// get data from server
return this.http.get(url)
.map((r: Response) => r.json() as string[]);
}
```

Call from a component:

```
//gets data from server
List.getData().subscribe(…)
```

More details and code example are here: http://devinstance.net/articles/20171021/rxjs-cacheable

Comment: Thanks for posting the links as part of your answer.

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way to cache the data inside a service is to involve `shareReplay()`

**`example.service.ts`**

```
import { shareReplay } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class ExampleService {

    private readonly _data: Observable<IExampleModel[]>;

    constructor(private readonly http: HttpClient) {
        this._data = 
            this.http.get<IExampleModel[]>('/api/example-entities/')
                .pipe(shareReplay());
        }
        
    getExampleEntities() : Observable<IExampleModel[]> {
        return this._data;
    }
}
```

An alternative widely used approach with `ReplaySubject<T>(1)` could be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42965625/1426685).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use http interceptors with angular 4+ versions. A very detailed and straight-forward implementation with explanation-https://www.concretepage.com/angular/angular-caching-http-interceptor

Answer (score 0):

For GET responses, you can try using this get shell component, which is super easy to use and set the cache configurations. [ngx-http-get-shell](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-http-get-shell)

```html
<ngx-http-get-shell [url]="url" [maxStale]="1000" [templateRef]="tmpl">
  <ng-template #tmpl let-data>
    {{ data | json }}
  </ng-template>
</ngx-http-get-shell>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents using ReplaySubject and race

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { race, ReplaySubject, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable()
export class RandomNumberService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  #number$ = this.newCache;

  private get newCache() {
    return new ReplaySubject<number>(1);
  }

  clearCache() {
    this.#number$ = this.newCache;
  }

  getNumber() {
    return this.http
      .get<{ number: number }>(
        '/api/random-number'
      )
      .pipe(map(({ number }) => number));
  }

  getNumberCachedVersion() {
    return race(
      this.#number$,
      this.getNumber().pipe(tap((number) => this.#number$.next(number)))
    );
  }

  getNumberCachedVersionWithRefreshParameter(refresh: boolean = false) {
    if (refresh) {
      this.clearCache();
    }

    return this.getNumberCachedVersion();
  }
}
```