# How to correctly use Observable and Angular async pipe?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, rxjs, observable

I tried using the Angular async pipe and got it working to display the time I get from the server using a http get request. I have the following questions:

- If I want to re-execute the http get request again to get updated data, is it correct to do what I'm doing in testAsync(), or is there a more elegant way to do this?
- Also I noticed some flickering going on when using the async pipe and re-requesting the data. This does not happen in the non-async version ("testNormal()"). Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

---

Angular component:

```js
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-async-test',
      templateUrl: './async-test.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./async-test.component.scss']
    })
    export class AsyncTestComponent implements OnInit {
      private readonly baseApiUrl = environment.baseApiUrl;
      httpServerRequest$ = this.http.get<ServerTimeViewModel>(`${this.baseApiUrl}/admin/servertime`);
    
      testNormalResult: Date = null;
      testAsyncResult$: Observable<Date> = null;
      
      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
      ) {}
    
      ngOnInit() {
          this.testAsync();
      }
    
      testNormal(): void {
        this.httpServerRequest$.subscribe(data => {
            this.testNormalResult = data.serverTime;
          });
      }
    
      testAsync(): void {   
        this.testAsyncResult$ = this.httpServerRequest$
          .map(d => d.serverTime);
      }
    }
```

ServerTimeViewModel class:

```js
    export class ServerTimeViewModel {
      serverTime: Date;
    }
```

template:

```html
    Test normal: {{ testNormalResult | date:'mediumTime'}}<br>
    Test async: {{ testAsyncResult$ | async | date:'mediumTime'}}<br>  
    <button type="button" (click)="testNormal()">test normal</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="testAsync()">test async</button>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554338/54159 helped me a lot. The solution was to use a ReplaySubject. Now refreshing from the web service does not result in any flickering anymore.

I've put it all in a data service. My component binds directly to dataService.person$ and calls dataService.fetchRandomPerson(x) to execute a new http get request.

Here's the DataService:

```js
    @Injectable()
    export class DataService {
      private readonly baseApiUrl = 'https://swapi.co/api';
    
      private personSubject = new ReplaySubject<Person>(1);
      person$: Observable<Person> = this.personSubject.asObservable();
    
      constructor(
        private http: HttpClient
      ) { }
    
      fetchRandomPerson(personId: number): void {
        // re-execute http get
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/41554338/54159
        this.http.get<Person>(`${this.baseApiUrl}/people/${personId}/`)
          .subscribe(res => this.personSubject.next(res));
        
        // note: no need to unsubscribe from http requests
        // https://stackoverflow.com/a/35043309/54159
      }
    }
```

Here's a running version:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dpbe7t

Answer (score 0):

Regarding your second question, to remove the flickering you should cache the server response. You can find more details in the angular [guide](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#an-impure-caching-pipe).

Answer (score 0):

**1**. If you want to re-execute the http get request again to get updated data, is it correct to do what I'm doing in testAsync(), or is there a more elegant way to do this?

> You are getting an Observable (not a Promise) with this in mind, you
>   do not need to "re-execute the http request to get the new data", that
>   data is coming to you as soon it gets on your server (or whatever is
>   you source data), that the purpose of an Observable (be observed and
>   watched fro changes).

**2**. Also I noticed some flickering going on when using the async pipe and re-requesting the data. This does not happen in the non-async version ("testNormal()"). Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

> That is the point of using an Observable, There are Observers (Ex: functions) always watching the data
>   changes on your source data. If you want to change this, you could use
>   a Promise instead (You can still use Promises on Angular). Also you if want to limit your response you can use the [take operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/take.html), there are also more of them just check them out.