# How do I make sure a HTTP request is only called once?

Tags: angular, http, rxjs

I have a back-end service that returns user details that I need on multiple Angular components. My problem is that it's obviously been called multiple times. Here is my get request:

```
getUser(): Observable<User> {
  if (this.user) {
    return Observable.of(this.user);
  } else {
    return this.http
      .get<User>(BACKENDPATH)
      .map((user: User) => new User().deserialise(user))
      .do((user) => {
        this.user = user;
        console.log(this.user.getUserName());
        return this.user;
      });
   }
}
```

I have tried the following methods after the get part of the function but none have worked:

- .publishReplay(1).refCount()
- .shareReplay()
- .shareReplay(1)

These methods have worked for others online so I'm guessing that I am doing something wrong with the implementation of them but I can't figure out what.

Comment: I guess it the request is sent many time because, before hitting the `this.user = user;` line, many components have called the method `getUser()`. Can you confirm?

Comment: @Picci Yes that's why but I believe that one of the purposes of the methods that I've posted is so that it won't make a get request multiple times

Comment: Your question is answered is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044291/using-sharereplay1-in-angular-still-invokes-http-request/51044495#51044495

Comment: @ShaneWatson The question is how you use `getUser()`. Do you call it multiple times? Or you make a single call then call `subscribe()` multiple times?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are creating a new stream with every `getUser()` call.
Solution: Make one `Http` request and work with cached/stored data. Use Below Approach

```
export class SharedService {

    data$: Observable<User>;
    getUser(): void {

        this.data$ = this.http
            .get<User>(BACKENDPATH)
            .map((user: User) => new User().deserialise(user))
            .do((user) => {
                this.user = user;
                console.log(this.user.getUserName());
                return this.user;
            }).shareReplay(1);
    }

    getData(): Observable<User> {
        return this.data$;
    }
}
```

Component:

```
this.service.getData().sub(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Vikas helped figure out this issue. This is my code now:

```
userData: Observable<User> = this.http
  .get<User>(BACKENDPATH)
  .map((user: User) => new User().deserialise(user))
  .shareReplay(1);

getUser(): Observable<User> {
  return this.userData;
}
```

Comment: If you are gonna invoke your method multiple times you would end up creating new stream with every invocation i.e multiple request will be triggered Better make one request and work with cached data.

Comment: Hi @Vikas I understand now and have updated by comment, it works. What do you think?