# Angular / RxJS service with http and replay

Tags: angular, rxjs

I need to create a SessionService which will contain information about user and should act as a singleton across all components.

I would use it like:

```
this.sessionService.user$.subscribe(_ => {
 this.greetingsName = _.firstName;
});
```

It should be lazy loading: first call should get data over http and store it somewhere, any other subscription should replay this stored data.

Can you advice any technique / pattern / best practice for this in Angular / RxJS ?

Thanks!

Comment: Hope this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51044291/using-sharereplay1-in-angular-still-invokes-http-request

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you want to have a service that is a singleton you have two options:

- set the `providedIn` property of the `@Injectable()` to "root"
- include the service in the `AppModule` or in a module that is only imported by the `AppModule`

As for the implementation of the service, this can do the `http` request you need and save the data in a `Subject`. I would suggest you use a [BehaviorSubject](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/behaviorsubject) to store the data received from the `http` request.