# Effective way to chain actions based on observable response Angular

Tags: angular

Assume a simple app.component setup where html has something along the lines of.

HTML

```
<div *ngIf="testObservable$ | async as testObservable">
hello world
</div>
```

TS

```
testObservable$: Observable<any>;
_testBehaviourSubject$ = new BehaviourSubject<any>(null);

constructor(public http: HttpClient) {
this.testObservable$ = this._testBehaviourSubject$.asObservable();
}

getData() {
return this.http.get(someApiURL).pipe(tap((e:any) => this._testBehaviourSubject$.next(any));
}
```

What is the best way to subscribe to getData() to update the BehaviourSubject IF it is null.

Essentially flow would be

```
listen for BehaviourSubject data as BSDATA
Event 1
    BSDATA is null
        do getData()
Event 2
    BSDATA is not null
        display 'Hello World'
```

Ideally I'd like to leverage the async pipe as opposed to triggering subscribe event manually.
Advice appreciated.

Comment: I think we're missing some information there. Why do you need `BehaviourSubject` at all? Seems you could just do: `this.testObservable$ = this.http.get(someApiURL)`

Comment: Sure, the intent behind behaviour subject is for data be shared across components. My next step is to migrate the BehaviourSubject to a service. That after it is loaded in first time by Component A, all others can use the same entity without calling server.

Comment: Then you can use `shareReplay` operator from `rxjs`. Here's an example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51044495/9932919